# How to find number of borrowed bits in subnetting

Tags: subnet

I am an Electrical Engineer learning about computer Networks, So this question might be childish and easy for most of you. Please answer it briefly.
I am performing subnetting where I have this address 192.10.10.0. In this worksheet, I can understand all the data except a number of borrowed bits which are 4. Please tell me How and from where this 4 came from? 
[image]
I have downloaded different worksheets and docs but was not able to understand this.

Comment: See the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499).

Comment: Could you explain me where is borrow part in the question you are linking to OR you are just a fan of marking duplicates?

Comment: There is a section called **Calculating subnets** that explains this. Also, understand that network classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1518 and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking does not use network classes. Please let them rest in peace. Also, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The borrowed bits are the **host bits** in the *default subnet mask* that are used for network in the *custom subnet mask*.

In your example:

Last byte of the *default subnet mask*:

```
Binary      Decimal
00000000 -> 0
```

Last byte of the *custom subnet mask*:

```
Binary      Decimal
11110000 -> 240
```

The first four (4) bits go from host to network, they are borrowed bits.

It can be understood easily using CIDR notation:

```
Netmask           CIDR Notation
255.255.255.255   32

Netmask           CIDR Notation
255.255.255.0     24

Netmask           CIDR Notation
255.255.255.240   28
```